# Keycloak authorization based on business attributes

Tags: keycloak

Here is how my application should work:

Users can use some functionalities of my application if they have enough chips (token) which they can buy from another application, or they can be granted to them upon some event, whatever. 
 
Users have an attribute associated with them called 'chip', which represents some number. This information should be represented as a claim, probably. 
I want Keycloak to do this authorization for me - to check whether user can use the functionality or not. I've come across JavaScript-based policies. It's seems they are able to operate on informations in tokens - like user email etc, but this is not my case where token can contain obsolete information, i.e. when token was generated user had enough chips but since then he spent them.


Maybe token should be refreshed upon spending chips, but in that case, would it be updated with current informations bound to user? Or maybe authorization service can somehow access database during evaluation of a policy? Could this work or are there any elegant solutions to this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak is not here to check if the user has enough money. Keycloak is here to say if the user is authenticated and if he has the roles for a certain application (admin, user...).

Checking if the user has enough money should be on server-side. For an incoming request, you have to check in the database if the user has enough chips to access the application and if he hasn't you return 403.

Comment: That is true for Role-based access control, but since Keycloak supports Context-based access control (CBAC) and Rule-based access control, I guess this can be achieved and they were intended for this, indeed.

Comment: I've looked at it, you're right, CBAC could work, Using the [Authorization Client Java API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_client_api). Maybe checking at each request with a simple database call ? 
But since accessing an application is using credits, you need to remove credits inside your application's server ? This leads to multiple services knowing how much the application costs. I can't find any elegant solution, the server is going to be involved in that credits verification anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for examining my problem.